# Kaltura listAction to return contextData as well

Tags: javascript, node.js, kaltura

Is there a way when using `listAction` to get all media entries to also retrieve `flavorAssets` of those media items? Currently what I am doing is retrieving all media items first, then iterating over each one and using `getContextData` action on to get `flavorAssets` for each media entry, which is not very effective and can take a long time. My question is, is there a way to do a `Kaltura.services.media.listAction(mediaFilter, pager)` while also returning `flavorAssets` or `contextData` in this case for each item without the need to call for `getContextData` action on each media entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use response profiles to return both the entries and the flavor assets in a single request.

Here's a raw request that will provide you with want you need, just append a KS:

http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/index.php?service=baseEntry&action=list&filter:objectType=KalturaBaseEntryFilter&filter:orderBy=-createdAt&format=1&responseProfile:objectType=KalturaDetachedResponseProfile&responseProfile:fields=id,name&responseProfile:type=1&responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:objectType=KalturaDetachedResponseProfileArray&responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:mappings:0:objectType=ResponseProfileMapping&responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:mappings:0:parentProperty=id&responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:mappings:0:filterProperty=entryIdEqual&responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:name=flavorAsset&&responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:filter:objectType=KalturaFlavorAssetFilter&ks=

In a more human friendly format:

```
service=baseEntry
action=list
format=1
filter:objectType=KalturaBaseEntryFilter
filter:orderBy=-createdAt
responseProfile:objectType=KalturaDetachedResponseProfile
responseProfile:fields=id,name
responseProfile:type=1
responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:objectType=KalturaDetachedResponseProfileArray
responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:name=flavorAsset
responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:mappings:0:objectType=ResponseProfileMapping
responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:mappings:0:parentProperty=id
responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:mappings:0:filterProperty=entryIdEqual
responseProfile:relatedProfiles:0:filter:objectType=KalturaFlavorAssetFilter
```

I'm not sure if the JavaScript client library support response profiles, the TypeScript client library does support it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue, just gotta figure out how to translate this to the `kaltura-client` module, but the raw request does what I needed.